# Rails sort columns by column name in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using handles_sortable_columns to sort my columns in Rails 3 and was wondering if there is a way to sort by a column in another table other than using a join.

I have a column that is a lookup of the name of a column in another table.

That is, I have cities.country_id as a column and in the View template I do:

```
@cities.each do |city|
    city.country.name
```

to display the name.

I would like to be able to sort by this column, but the `countries.name`, not the `cities.country_id`.

Does anyone know if this possible with the gem or any other simple way? If so how?

The only thing I can think of is to do an IF statement in the controller and catch the sorting by country and then run a different query using a join for that, but that's ugly and error-prone, was hoping for something more elegant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to use a join to get the right data to begin with. While Webjedi's answer is quite intriguing I didn't want to override any built-in functions, but it's good to know I can do that.

The code looks like this:

```
@countries = Country.select('countries.*, continents.name AS continent_name').joins{continent}.search(params[:term]).order(order).page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you override to the to_s on the country model to return the name, then sort by that in the controller?

In your country model override to_s by:

```
def to_s
 country.name
end
```

Then in your controller

```
@sorted_cities = @cities.sort_by { |obj| obj.country.to_s }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: This is really interesting. I'd never seen it before. In the end I went with a join so I could also query on the country name, but thanks a lot for pointing this out. I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Webjedi answer..

```
 @sorted_cities = @cities.includes(:country).sort_by { |obj| obj.country.to_s } #for eager loading
```

Comment: Don't do this. You should use the database.